# Excel showing as #REF

Tags: excel, ref

I am using mac laptop. There is an excel sent to my team by another person and windows users are able to see the data without any issues but when i open most of the fields show as #REF!. Any idea how i can resolve this?

UPDATE:

Weirdly , when i opened another excel which is connecting to DB and getting the data and then opened the above mentioned excel then i do not see #REF! error anymore. Values are getting displayed.
Now, if i close both excels and open the original excel then i see the #REF! again.

Only when the excel connecting to DB is opened and then the original excel is opened, the values are displayed.
I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Normally that error is because a cell involved in a formula has been deleted or a source object. Check [How to correct a #REF! error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-ref-error-822c8e46-e610-4d02-bf29-ec4b8c5ff4be?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: What is the file type (.xlsx, .xlsb etc) and what does the formula that returns #REF! look like? Make sure you trace the error back to the first formula/function that returns #REF!, and not a formula that inherits it. Formula evaluation can be a useful tool in this situation.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Other windows user have no issue in seeing the data. Its just me facing this issue

Comment: Did they get sent a second sheet / workbook previously?

Comment: @SolarMike I am receiving this excel for first time whereas other users are receiving this since long back.

Comment: @ThomasLilleng It is an xlsx file

Comment: Can you post the formula that returns the #REF!-error? It's hard to analyze your problem without more details

Comment: @ThomasLilleng It is actually multiple cells that are showing the #REF!. Some of them use GETPIVOTDATA formula and other cells are mostly referencing this and taking an sum of value or doing an %calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. It is just how excel work. As you had said :

> the excel connecting to DB is opened and then the original excel is opened, the values are displayed.

For some reason excel do need the source file to be opened to 'load' its value. Somehow (in my case) using the " Data > Get External Data " can work without the source file being opened. (maybe this answers `Any idea how i can resolve this?`).

Anyway, please share if the Get External Data works for u or not. (also mention your excel version).